# linq to xml, read xml file

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am struggling to read this xml file in linq to xml. Can someone help me here.
I need to read each track information.

```
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" xmlns:jwplayer="http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashFormats">
<title>Some title here</title>
<creator>Some creater</creator>
<info>somesite.com</info>
    <trackList>
        <track>
            <title>Title 1</title>
            <creator>Creater 1</creator>
            <location>location 1</location>
        </track>
        <track>
            <title>Title 2</title>
            <creator>Creater 2</creator>
            <location>location 2</location>
        </track>
    </trackList>
</playlist>
```

This is what I am trying to do.

```
XElement xelement1 = XElement.Load(@"pathtoxmlfile\my.xml");

IEnumerable<XElement> tracks= xelement1.Elements();
// Read the entire XML
foreach (var track in tracks.Descendants("track"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(track );
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I am using C#.

Thanks
Parminder

Comment: That's really really easy, did you try anything so far?

Comment: Well how far have you got? I suspect you're getting confused due to the namespaces, but without seeing what you've tried, we can't see what's wrong.

Comment: i have updated the question. thanks guys for helping. i am not in touch with c# for more than 1 year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why do you load your document into `XElement` instead of `XDocument`?
2. You have to use `XNamespace` instance within your query because your document uses default namespace `xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/"`.

   ```
   var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://xspf.org/ns/0/");
   ```
3. You can use LINQ query to get a collection with your data extracted from XML document. Then you can iterate over that collection and do whatever you need.

   ```
   var tracks = (from t in xDoc.Root.Element(ns + "trackList").Elements(ns + "track")
                 select new
                 {
                     Title = (string)t.Element(ns + "title"),
                     Creator = (string)t.Element(ns + "creator"),
                     Location = (string)t.Element(ns + "location")
                 }).ToList();
   ```

   `tracks` will be a `List<T>` where `T` is anonymous type with 3 `string` properties: `Title`, `Creator` and `Location`.

Comment: Thanks MarcinJuraszek. Works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to include namespace name, do the following changes:

```
    XNamespace defNs = "http://xspf.org/ns/0/";
```

And

```
    foreach (var track in tracks.Descendants(defNs + "track"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XElement tracks = XElement.Load(@"pathtoxmlfile\my.xml");  
foreach (var track in tracks.Descendants("track"))
{
  Console.WriteLine((string)track.Element("title"));
  Console.WriteLine((string)track.Element("creator"));
  Console.WriteLine((string)track.Element("location"));
}
```